# Scala XML: Parsing parent text that may contain other XML elements within

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I need to parse an XML node that may or may not contain other XML within its text:

#### input

```
<! -- i. no xml nested within text --> 
<my.element>
  This is some text. It's simple and easy.
</my.element>

<! -- ii. no xml nested within text --> 
<my.element>
  This is some text. It comes with <other.xml ID="1234" type="x" ...>1</other.xml> xml element nested within it's text.
</my.element>
```

#### output

```
# i.
"This is some text. It's simple and easy."

# ii.
"This is some text. It comes with [1] other xml element nested within its text."
```

#### The problem is how to reliably separate the `my.element` text from the  nested element `other.xml`'s text.

Each element is loaded as a `scala.xml.NodeSeq`, and it's as if the inner xml is more or less ignored (i.e. can't apply logic to it via `label`).  The best I can do is get `text`. Which duplicates the `text` of the inner elements:

```
foo.text
String = 
"This is some text. It comes with
    1
    1
    other xml element nested within its text."
```

This is a simple example. In reality I'm working with a TB or more of data and need to handle a widely variable number of potentially nested xml elements. Some to have the text extracted and incorporated like above, some to ignore, some to format differently etc.

This is related to Spark in that I need the solution to be serializable and run at scale using Spark.

Comment: how is the `apache-spark` tag related to this question?

Comment: @TzachZohar I need the solution to be serializable so I can run it at scale using Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on scala-xml but I would normalize that xml block beforehand such that you end up with something like

```
<! -- i. no xml nested within text --> 
<my.element>
  This is some text. It's simple and easy.
</my.element>

<! -- ii. no xml nested within text --> 
<my.element>
  <textblock>This is some text. It comes with</textblock> <other.xml ID="1234" type="x" ...>1</other.xml><textblock> xml element nested within it's text.</textblock>
</my.element>
```

Then you can simply get to your element and call `(xmlObj / "textblock").text`

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I get when I call `text`

```
scala> val foo = <my.element>This is some text. It comes with <other.xml ID="1234" type="x">1</other.xml> xml element nested within it's text. </my.element>
foo: scala.xml.Elem = <my.element>This is some text. It comes with <other.xml ID="1234" type="x">1</other.xml> xml element nested within it's text. </my.element>

scala> foo.text
res0: String = "This is some text. It comes with 1 xml element nested within it's text. "
```

You can get a collection of the children in `my.element` by using `child` method:

```
scala> foo.child
res4: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = ArrayBuffer(This is some text. It comes with , <other.xml ID="1234" type="x">1</other.xml>,  xml element nested within it's text. )
```

And then filter (with `collect`) the text but not the XML elements:

```
scala> foo.child.collect { case scala.xml.Text(data) => data }
res6: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer("This is some text. It comes with ", " xml element nested within it's text. ")
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but this is how to do based on what you asked.  I hope that helps.